# Rolling a dice based on number of sides

Tags: java, android

EDIT: See included error log.

I am trying to create a simple app to roll different sided dice in Android Studio.
This is my code so far:
MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.thomb.tutorialspoint;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioButton;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRoll);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int roll = RollDice(sidesChosen);
            TextView tv1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            tv1.setText(roll);
            setContentView(tv1);
        }
    });
}

public int sidesChosen;
public int RollDice(int sides) {
    Random r = new Random();
    return r.nextInt(sides)+1;
} //method
public void onRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    // Is the button now checked?
    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();

    // Check which radio button was clicked
    switch(view.getId()) {
        case R.id.radioButtonD4:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 4;
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonD6:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 6;
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonD8:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 8;
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonD10:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 10;
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonD12:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 12;
                break;
        case R.id.radioButtonD20:
            if (checked)
                sidesChosen = 20;
                break;
    } //switch
} //method
} //class
```

This is how the layout looks like:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/adpP1.png

The app crashes when i click the roll button, but I've no idea why. The ID's are all correct and the radio buttons works as expected.
I am using API level 25. I am fairly new to Java, but I am quite familiar with C#, so the problem may lie in the code syntax, although Android Studio reports no errors. Let me know if you need to see the XML for the layout as well.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.thomb.tutorialspoint, PID: 5029
              java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:4310)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4146)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4087)
                  at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4060)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:279)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:145)
                  at com.example.thomb.tutorialspoint.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:25)
                  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5280)
                  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21239)
                  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:234)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5526)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have you used the logcat while running the app? you need to put more info about the crash, the logcat would tell why it's crashing.

Comment: If you are familiar with C# I assume you are also familiar with debugging. When app crashes it produces crash report indicating what caused the crash and other very useful data. Start investigating the crash report and if you still have problems you can post it here.

Comment: for me, the code looks incomplete. What is R? what is R.id with all the check boxes... are those the controls, or already boolean values? It R.id.radioButtonD4 is the radio button, you will need to get the id (or name) of the radios in your case statements.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. Sorry for not including the crash report, it is included in the original post now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setText()` is a overloaded method with two types: one that takes in a `String`, the other an `int`. The `int` here should be string resource ID. This is where your error is. In the code below you're using `setText(int)` but not passing a valid string resource ID.

```
int roll = RollDice(sidesChosen);
...
tv1.setText(roll);
```

Do `setText(String.valueOf(roll)` to convert it to a String first

EDIT after log post:

The cause of your error is that you're passing 0 to the `nextInt()` method. This might happen because you've never selected a RadioButton (sidesChosen is 0 by default) or that even after selecting a RadioButton, none of the `case`s of the `switch` is entered.

EDIT after second log post: (...)

Remove `setContentView(tv1);` This is used to attach a layout to an activity. Why are you using it here?

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep that in mind! Though I am still experiencing an error. It seems it might be related to the use of the Random class.

Comment: Well i see your error log now. After you fix that, this is the next one you were going to encounter :)

Comment: Yup, I fixed the TextView and Random errors, but I am getting a new one now, which I have included in the original post.

Answer (score 1):

It seems, that you pass `0` to the `Random.nextInt()` method, which is not allowed.

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: n <= 0: 0
              at java.util.Random.nextInt(Random.java:182)
```

This happens, if none of your `case` branches is reached. So it seems, there is something wrong with how you handle the radio button clicks.